# how to i make warn command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

my command in warn.js

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'warn',
  commands: 2,
  expectedArgs: "<Target user's @> <reason>",
  requiredRoles: ['Admin'],
  callback: (message, arguments) => {
    const target = message.mentions.users.first()
    if (!target) {
      message.reply('Please specify a MEMEBR to warn!!')
      return
    }

    arguments.shift()

    const guildId = message.guild.id
    const userId = message.member.id
    const reason = arguments.join(' ')

    console.log(guildId, userId, reason)
  },
}
```

my code in index.js

```
else if (command == 'warn'){
      client.commands.get('warn').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    }
```

my error

```
/home/runner/discord-quack-admin/index.js:85
      client.commands.get('warn').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
                                  ^

TypeError: client.commands.get(...).execute is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/runner/discord-quack-admin/index.js:85:35)
    at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at Client.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/home/runner/discord-quack-admin/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/home/runner/discord-quack-admin/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/runner/discord-quack-admin/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/runner/discord-quack-admin/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/runner/discord-quack-admin/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/runner/discord-quack-admin/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
```

I AM VERY NEW ON DISCORD.JS SO PLEASE EXPLAIN ME WHAT TO DO AND IF POSSIBLE PLZ RE-WRITE THE CODE TO HELP ME

Comment: Please do not write in all caps, it's ANNOYING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the warning command I use. I currently don't have it save the warnings in a log but that can be easily added. It does store that a user has been warned in a .json file. At 5 warning the user will be auto muted for the default amount of time. The things you need to change are the muted role, and where the bot will be sending the logs of the actions.

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'warn',
    aliases: ['warn'],
    category: 'staff',
    utilisation: '{prefix}help <command name>',

    execute(client, message, args) {
        const Discord = require("discord.js");
        const mutedroleid = '818147666785337406';
        const fs = require('fs');
        const mutedrole = message.guild.roles.cache.get(mutedroleid);
        const warns = require("./warns.json");
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MUTE_MEMBERS")) return message.send("I cannot let you do that");
        const user = message.mentions.users.first();
        if (!user) return message.send("Please specify someone you want to warn. **&warn <user> [reason]**");
        const target = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
        if(target.roles.cache.has(mutedroleid)) return message.reply("You cannot warn muted members.");
        if(!mutedrole) return message.send("Couldn't find the Muted role.");
        message.delete()
        const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if(!warns[user.id]) {
            warns[user.id] = {
                warnCount: 1
            }
        } else {
            warns[user.id].warnCount += 1;
        }
        if(warns[user.id].warnCount >= 5) {
            const mute = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#ff7b23")
            .setDescription(`${user} has been muted. (**5**/**5**)\nReason: **${reason != "" ? reason : "-"}**`);
            message.channel.send(mute);
            message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).send(mute)
            let botlog = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name === "bot-logs");
            botlog.send(mute);
            target.roles.add(mutedrole.id);
            warns[user.id].warnCount = 0;
            setTimeout(() => {
                target.roles.remove(mutedrole.id);
                const unmute = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#23ff82")
                .setDescription(`${user} has been unmuted.`);
                message.channel.send(unmute);
                message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).send(unmute)
            }, 1000 * 900);
        } else {
            const warn = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#ffd641")
            .setDescription(`${user} has been warned by ${message.author}. (**${warns[user.id].warnCount}**/**5**) \nReason: **${reason != "" ? reason : "-"}**`);
            message.channel.send(warn);
            message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).send(warn)
            let botlog = message.guild.channels.cache.find(x => x.name === "bot-logs");
            botlog.send(warn);
        }
        fs.writeFile("./warns.json", JSON.stringify(warns), err => {
            if (err) console.log(err);
        });
    },
};
```

.json file format. Keep this file in the main folder of your bot. Sometimes it creates the file sometimes it does not.

```
{}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of storing data in JSON. It's a very bad idea. Use something like [`enmap`](https://npmjs.com/package/enmap), [JOSH](https://npmjs.com/package/@joshdb/core) or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your mixture of other command handlers.

In a system like this, it all has to be consistent.

Your command defines `callback`, but you call `execute`.

You also cannot use `arguments` as a parameter (or at least, you shouldn't).

Fixed definition:

```js
  execute: (message, args, Discord, client) => {
```

Your code will still error. Stop copying code from random places without knowing what it does, as it will result in a mess like this. [I'd suggest to learn the basics of JS first](https://codecademy.com)